# How many tests to validate an identity?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

Discrete formulas such as the Faulhaber summations can be verified by evaluating them for a finite number of values.

For example $$\sum_{k=1}^nk=\frac{n(n+1)}2$$ is validated by evaluating for $n=0,1,2$ (indeed $0=0,0+1=2/2,0+1+2=2\cdot3/2$) because both sides are quadratic polynomials.

Can we generalize the approach to other kinds of formulas ? For instance, how many trials for 
$$\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}2^k = 3^n$$

Comment: How do you show that the LHS of the first formula (Faulhaber summation) is a quadratic function?

Comment: Because the first order finite difference is a linear function (namely $n$).

Comment: So I would say that there is no gain in using this approach, as with that you can almost guess the value of the function. If you are a professor, consider tell your students to guess the value of the function by looking to the fewest possible numbers, assuming that the function belongs to a prescribed set (to me it's not clear what set would belong $\sum \binom{n}{k} 2^k $.
If you are a student answer zero and show the equality.

Comment: I should add, there's definitely no "correct" answer here, as $3$ wouldn't be a correct answer in the previous one. By using induction you have only to show that those functions coincide in one value and that the finite differences are identically the same.

Comment: @PenasRaul: the purpose is to verify an identity that has been established by other means. I am convinced that a finite number of attempts is enough to serve as a proof and I would like to get insight on the rules.

Comment: You know that the polynomials of degree at most two form a three dimensional vector space. You know that evaluating polynomials at real numbers are linearly independent linear maps (if you didn't, check out Vendermonde's matrix).

With that knowledge I would say that what you are asking is, in full generality, $n$ linearly independent linear maps to classify a point in a vector space. I could give you the linear maps if you tell me the vector space, but I have absolutely no idea what vector space you are considering when evaluation the function $\sum \binom{n}{k} 2^k$.

Comment: I.e., you want to distinguish this function from others, which ones?

Comment: @PenasRaul: that belongs to the question as well.

Comment: In the case of Faulhaber's formula, I believe there is a way to show that the summation of $k^p$ is a polynomial of degree $p+1$ without finding the coefficients of the polynomial. For the sum of something that isn't a polynomial in the index of summation, I think you'd want to show that things of that form sum to members of some other family of functions, and then find the minimum number of "test points" that determine a member of that family of functions. For $\sum_{k=0}^n \binom nk 2^k$, without knowing it equals $3^n$, what family of functions can we say it belongs to, and how do we know?

Comment: @DavidK: it is allowed to use knowledge of the RHS.

Comment: My point is you _must_ have some knowledge of the RHS. Given a LHS of $\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk2^k$, if I _know_ the RHS is $3^n$, then I can "verify" the formula in zero trials. What kind of knowledge might we reasonably have about the RHS that is less specific than "it is $3^n$", and how would we get that knowledge? I think that is the first step toward an answer.

Comment: @DavidK: this is the core of my question.